# Bash Shell Script Variable Value Check for integer and number range

Tags: bash, shell

im trying to do a Number Check not including decimals as well as within range check but it is not working

```
example of accepted numbers: 1, 10, 100
not accepted numbers: 1.1, 10.1, 100.1



echo "Qty Sold: "
read sold 
if [[ "$sold" =~ `^([0-9])$` && "$sold" -gt 0 && "$sold" -lt 999 ]] ;
then    
echo "ok"   
else     
echo "Error, Qty Sold Must be Positive Integer";
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the backticks which exists around your regex and use + after `[0-9]` to match one or more digits.

```
if [[ "$sold" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$sold" -gt 0 && "$sold" -lt 999 ]] ;
```

*Example:*

```
$ sold=12
$ if [[ "$sold" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$sold" -gt 0 && "$sold" -lt 999 ]] ; then echo 'Ok'; else echo 'NOT ok'; fi
Ok
$ sold=0
$ if [[ "$sold" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$sold" -gt 0 && "$sold" -lt 999 ]] ; then echo 'Ok'; else echo 'NOT ok'; fi
NOT ok
$ sold=1000
$ if [[ "$sold" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$sold" -gt 0 && "$sold" -lt 999 ]] ; then echo 'Ok'; else echo 'NOT ok'; fi
NOT ok
```

Comment: Thank you very much! forgot about the +

Answer (score 1):

Without using regex:

```
((sold>0 && sold <999)) 2>/dev/null && echo "ok" || echo "Error, Qty Sold Must be Positive Integer"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[[` syntax is a bit different from `[` syntax. You do not need any delimiter around the regex in `=~`. So no `/` or backtick or apostrophe or ampersand is needed (only if regex contains a space. It can be escaped by backslash or add apostrophe or ampersand around the space or use [[:space:]] instead (which also includes TAB and some other whitespace characters)). What is more the ampersand also not needed around `$sold` (only in `[[`!). So the conditional part may be like this

```
if [[ $sold =~ ^[[:digit:]]{1,3}$ && $sold -gt 0 && $sold -lt 999 ]]; then echo ok
else  echo "Error, Qty Sold Must be Positive Integer between 1 and 998";
fi
```

This checks if one, two or three digits are entered and it is not zero.